# std::invoke - perfect forwarding functor

Tags: c++, c++17

Trying to understand why the following example fails to compile:

```cpp
#include <functional>

template <typename F>
void f1(F&& f)
{
  std::forward<F>(f)("hi");
}

template <typename F>
void f2(F&& f)
{
  std::invoke(f, "hi");  // works but can't perfect forward functor
}

template <typename F>
void f3(F&& f)
{
  std::invoke<F>(f, "hi");
}

int main()
{
  f1([](const char*) {});  // ok
  f2([](const char*) {});  // ok
  f3([](const char*) {});  // error
}
```

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) says the following about `std::invoke`:

> 1. Invoke the Callable object `f` with the parameters args. As by `INVOKE(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...)`. This overload participates in overload resolution only if `std::is_invocable_v<F, Args...>` is true.

So why is `f3` not equivalent to `f1`?

Comment: @JeJo I don't think the `std::forward` in `f1` is redundant. `F` can be a type that behaves differently depending on whether its `operator()` is invoked on an lvalue or an rvalue of `F`: https://godbolt.org/z/f3sjcPK14

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::invoke` is itself a function. In your case, its first parameter is a rvalue reference while `f` is a lvalue, so the error occurs.

`INVOKE(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...)` is executed after the function `std::invoke` is properly selected and called. Basically, your lambda function is passed as follows:

```
original lambda in main -> the parameter of f3 -> the parameter of std::invoke -> the parameter of INVOKE
```

So the `std::forward` in `INVOKE(std::forward<F>(f), std::forward<Args>(args)...)` is used in the last step, while you need to forward the lambda in the middle step (the parameter of `f3` -> the parameter of `std::invoke`). I guess this is where your confusion comes.

Answer (score 2):

Because you need to `std::forward<F>(f)` to `std::invoke()`:

```cpp
template <typename F>
void f3(F&& f)
{
  std::invoke<F>(std::forward<F>(f), "hi"); // works
}
```

Consider the difference between these two calls:

```
void f(const int&) { std::cout << "const int&" << std::endl; }
void f(int&&) { std::cout << "int&&" << std::endl; }

int main()
{
  std::cout << "first" << std::endl;
  int&& a = 3;
  f(a);
  std::cout << "second" << std::endl;
  int&& b = 4;
  f(std::forward<int>(b));
}
```

The output is

```
first
const int&
second
int&&
```

If you remove the `const int&` overload, you even get a compiler error for the first call:

```
error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type 'int&&' to lvalue of type 'int'
```

The `std::forward()` is necessary for passing the correct type to `std::invoke()`.

Comment: I see. And I think `std::invoke<F>(std::forward<F>(f), "hi");` and `std::invoke(std::forward<F>(f), "hi");` are equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're getting this error:

> note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
> note:   cannot convert ‘f’ (type ‘main()::<lambda(const char*)>’) to type ‘main()::<lambda(const char*)>&&’

That's because inside the function `f3`, `f` is an L-value, but the `invoke` expects an R-value. For template argument deduction/substitution to work, the types have to match EXACTLY.

When you perfect forward `f` to `invoke`, this issue is resolved as you passed an R-value originally from outside `f3`.